# Using a query result to set table of next query

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have the following query that returns the min, max and user total of basically unique rows
in two different tables.

```
select sum(user_count) as user_count_sum, sum(min_count) as min_count_sum, 
sum(max_count) as max_count_sum
from(
select max(case when di = 'i' then di_count end) as user_count, 
       min(di_count) as min_count,
       max(di_count) as max_count
from (
    select di, 
           count(distinct rt) as di_count
    from gpstablev2 
    where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
    group by di
)
UNION
select max(case when di = 'i' then di_count end) as user_count, 
       min(di_count) as min_count,
       max(di_count) as max_count
from (
    select di, 
           count(distinct rt) as di_count
    from powertablev2 
    where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
    group by di
)
)
```

Now I also have a master table, that if I were to run the following query would return the following

```
select table from mastertable;

gpstablev2
powertablev2
...(more table names)
```

Instead of pasting 9 more UNION blocks like the one I have to sum all the tables listed in `mastertable`, is there a way I can use a query to `mastertable` to clean this up?

If I were doing this in java I would have first get my ResultSet from master table and then do 10 queries and `UNION` them myself. But I rather have my database do ALL the processing, and be able to update based on the contents of `mastertable`.

EDIT:
Based on feedback I am trying a Dynamic Query and have gotten this far, but am still have trouble putting together the rest of the pieces

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_sums()
RETURNS TABLE(user_count_sum bigint, min_count_sum bigint, max_count_sum bigint)
$BODY$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE "
SELECT $$SELECT sum(user_count) AS user_count_sum
      ,sum(min_count) AS min_count_sum
      ,sum(max_count) AS max_count_sum
FROM  (
   SELECT max(case when di = 'id' then di_count end) AS user_count
         ,min(di_count) AS min_count
         ,max(di_count) AS max_count
   FROM  ($$
||
string_agg(format($$
      (SELECT di, count(distinct rt) AS di_count
       FROM   %I
       WHERE  rt >  now() - interval '1 day'
       GROUP  BY 1)$$, tbl)
      ,'

      UNION ALL')
|| '
      ) sub1
   ) sub2'
FROM   mastertable;
INTO results_var"

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpqsql;
```

Comment: You can do that with dynamic SQL (google for `EXECUTE`) inside a PL/pgSQL function.

Comment: I see just looking for a little more direction how to execute Dynamic SQL. Trying to learn from this example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028041/select-a-dynamic-set-of-columns-from-a-table-and-get-the-sum-for-each/12031145#12031145

Comment: Type definitions are missing. Should be: `RETURNS TABLE(user_count_sum bigint, min_count_sum bigint, max_count_sum bigint)`. The rest looks good now on a quick glance.

Answer (score 0):

You need **dynamic SQL** for that. SQL does not accept the dynamic conversion of literals / values to identifiers. So you need to build the query first and then execute it. You can do this in your client (seems to be Java), or do it *all* inside Postgres, which is generally fastest:

```
SELECT $$SELECT sum(user_count) AS user_count_sum
      ,sum(min_count)  AS min_count_sum
      ,sum(max_count)  AS max_count_sum
FROM  (
   ($$
||
string_agg(format($$
   SELECT max(case when di = 'i' then di_count end) AS user_count
         ,min(di_count) AS min_count
         ,max(di_count) AS max_count
   FROM  (
      SELECT di, count(distinct rt) AS di_count
      FROM   %I
      WHERE  rt >  now() - interval '1 day'
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) t
   )$$, tbl)
      ,'

   UNION ALL
   (')
|| '
   ) sub'
FROM   mastertable;
```

Produces the query-string:

```
SELECT sum(user_count) AS user_count_sum
      ,sum(min_count)  AS min_count_sum
      ,sum(max_count)  AS max_count_sum
FROM  (
   (
   SELECT max(case when di = 'i' then di_count end) AS user_count
         ,min(di_count) AS min_count
         ,max(di_count) AS max_count
   FROM  (
      SELECT di, count(distinct rt) AS di_count
      FROM   gpstablev2
      WHERE  rt >  now() - interval '1 day'
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) t
   )

   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT max(case when di = 'i' then di_count end) AS user_count
         ,min(di_count) AS min_count
         ,max(di_count) AS max_count
   FROM  (
      SELECT di, count(distinct rt) AS di_count
      FROM   powertablev2
      WHERE  rt >  now() - interval '1 day'
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) t
   )

   UNION ALL
   ...

   ) sub;
```

- `GETDATE()` is not a valid Postgres function. You probably mean `now()` or `CURRENT_DATE` .. depending on the undisclosed type of `rt`. I use **`now()`** instead.
- You most probably want to use **`UNION ALL`** instead of `UNION` here.
- Also fixed missing aliases for subqueries and made some minor simplifications.

Wrap this into a **plpgsql** function with `EXECUTE`. There are [plenty of closely related examples here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[plpgsql]+[dynamic-sql]+EXECUTE+string_agg) with code and links and explanation ...

Comment: Your query is different from the query in question. You need to move max/min aggregates to every subquery.